# how to create transparent dialog ( not invisible) but image or text drawn on it is visible in MFC?

Tags: mfc

how to create transparent dialog but image or text drawn on it is visible in MFC.
I searched many articles but didn't get exactly what i want. 
I want to deploy this in my project.
help can be appreciated please help.

Comment: Could you draw some image of what you want exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In OnInitDialog you put this:

```
SetWindowLong(m_hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, GetWindowLong(m_hWnd,GWL_EXSTYLE) ^ WS_EX_LAYERED);
SetLayeredWindowAttributes(m_hWnd, RGB(255,0,255), 0, LWA_COLORKEY);
```

`RGB(255,0,255)` is the [COLORREF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183449%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for magenta. We suppose here that you don't use the color magenta anywhere in your dialog. With that all magenta pixels of your dialog will be transparent. As you want only the background to be transparent, we will paint the background of the dialog in magenta. This is done via the WM_ERASEBKGND message:

In the message map of your dialog add `ON_WM_ERASEBKGND()`, so your message map should look like this :

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CYourDialogDlg, CDialog)
//{{AFX_MSG_MAP(CYourDialogDlg)
...
//}}AFX_MSG_MAP
  ON_WM_ERASEBKGND()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

In the header file of your dialog you should have `afx_msg BOOL OnEraseBkgnd(CDC* pDC);`

In the .cpp file of your dialog put this :

```
BOOL CYourDialogDlg::OnEraseBkgnd(CDC *pDC)
{
  CRect clientRect ;

  GetClientRect(&clientRect) ;
  pDC->FillSolidRect(clientRect, RGB(255,0,255)) ;  // paint background in magenta

  return FALSE  ;
}
```

[image: Sample dialog as visible in the dialog editor and as visible once executed]

Comment: hi,
if i paint with magneta, then i will see that color as background. but i want background to be transparent. yes?

Comment: You must add the SetLayeredWindowAttributes stuff as explained at the beginning of my answer. If you don't, the background will be displayed in magenta. If you do so, everything that is magenta will be transparent. I edited the answer and included a picture, I suppose this is what you want.

Comment: really i must appreciate you!!! you helped me so much

Comment: Michael Walz absolute fantastic :). can you answer me one more question?