# MFC: Adding fade-in , fade-out effect to polygon region

Tags: mfc, mfcc

I Want To Fade-in, Fade-out a particular region created by me. but when i use animatewindow()
It fades out entire window which is not visible earlier when i created polygon region.
how do i do this? help can be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
Use the SetLayeredWindowAttributes like this :

```
for (int opacity = 0; opacity <= 255; opacity++)
{
  ::SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hWnd, RGB(0,0,0), opacity, LWA_ALPHA);
  Sleep(20) ;
}
```

This will fade out the hWnd window in approximately 5 seconds. The hWnd window  must be created with the WS_EX_LAYERED extended style.

Comment: hi,
sleep() i cannot use.. as it stops the execution flow for that time..
Any better solution than this?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer.. :) you removed many speed breaks in my project :)

Comment: Instead of using Sleep you could use a timer (WM_TIMER message).

Comment: hi michael walz can you also provide me correct answer for my other question related to transparent dialogs in MFC. i hope you have an answer for that :) please help and remove my last hurdle in my project 

you can refer that in my profile please help !! :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17251692/how-to-create-transparent-dialog-not-invisible-but-image-or-text-drawn-on-it

Comment: @user2059287: just posted an aswer to that question.